# How do I grab a TextView in a class via context of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an activity where I grab a textview normallythen I have a separate class thats needs that textview to modify it

```
//textview
 this.tvUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);

 new GetData(context,params,method,preText);
```

I want to get this same view in a seperate class without having to pass it in the constructor.

```
 public class GetData {

private ProgressBar pbTitle;
private TextView tvUpdate;
private Context context;
private String preText,method;
private String[] params;

public void getData(Context context,String[] params, String method,String preText){
    this.context = context;

            //how do i get this text view?
    this.tvUpdate = ???

             this.params = params;
    this.method = method;
}
}
```

not sure if this is possible.

Edit working line of code

```
tvUpdate = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work.

```
this.tvUpdate = ((YourActivity) context) findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View yourView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
this.tvUpdate = (TextView) yourView.findViewById(R.id.tvUpdate);
```

Comment: actually still having some issues. The code doesn't have any errors but I can't manipulate the view.

Comment: what's the error you are getting, you can't see the TextView ?